# How to capture event on event box to detect mouse movement in gtk?

Tags: c, events, gtk

Right now I have a `motion_notify_event` on an `event_box` to track mouse coordinates. I can detect motion only if I click on the `event_box` does any one know how I can capture the event on the `event_box` when the mouse is over so I don't have to click on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to listen to the `"motion-notify-event"` signal. Make sure you also enable the `GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK` flag.

Comment: How to enable the flag ?

Comment: @Sagar `gtk_widget_add_events(event_box, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);`

Comment: And how to do it in Python?
([my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58683788/978288 "Gtk: How to detect the mouse position over EventBox?"))