# Gtk: How to detect the mouse position over EventBox?

Tags: python, gtk

I have been trying to write simple CAD application in Python. I was tinkering with pyglet, got some results: [image: simple CAD app with pyglet], but I decided to switch back to Gtk and I hit the wall:

I cannot **get the mouse pointer position over the EventBox** (with pyglet it was the label in the bottom left corner of the window app in the picture). What signal is designed for it? Or should I use another approach?

I will appreciate any piece of information or resources. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture event on event box to detect mouse movement in gtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281782/how-to-capture-event-on-event-box-to-detect-mouse-movement-in-gtk)

Comment: Edit: I am looking for solution in Python

Comment: In the "Possible duplicate" I found `motion_notify_event`, I set the connection: `box.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_mouse_move)`, but it works only when the area is clicked.
The remaining question: how to set `GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK` on the box, in python?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201848/discussion-between-khaz-and-stovfl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: How to detect the mouse position over EventBox?

- [how-to-capture-event-on-event-box-to-detect-mouse-movement-in-gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281782/how-to-capture-event-on-event-box-to-detect-mouse-movement-in-gtk)
- [Gtk.EventBox](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/EventBox.html)

  > The `Gtk.EventBox` widget is a subclass of `Gtk.Bin` which also has its own window. It is useful since it allows you to catch events for widgets which do not have their own window.
- [Gtk.Widget.add_events(events)](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.add_events)

  > Adds the `events` in the bitfield `events` to the event mask for `self`.
- [Gdk.EventMask](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.EventMask)

  > A set of bit-flags to indicate which events a window is to receive.
  >
  > - [GDK_MOTION_NOTIFY](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
  >     the pointer (usually a mouse) has moved

The `Gtk.EventBox` should have got the flag, not the window!

```
box = Gtk.EventBox()
box.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_mouse_move)
box.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **stovfl** the solution was achieved.
The application
[image: a simple CAD in python/gtk] 
consisted of a drawing area, a frame, an event box and a label, for displaying of the mouse pointer coordinates. The drawing area was added to the box, the box was added to the frame, which was added to the grid.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk
# (...)
    box = Gtk.EventBox()
    box.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)  # 1
    box.connect("button-press-event", self.on_click)
    box.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_mouse_move)  # 2
    self.canvas = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    self.canvas.connect("draw", self.on_draw)
    self.canvas.set_size_request(800, 600)
    box.add(self.canvas)
    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    frame = Gtk.Frame()
    frame.set_label("KHAD")
    frame.add(box)
    grid.attach(frame, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.add(grid)
    # (...)
    self.locationLabel = Gtk.Label("X,Y")
    self.locationLabel.set_alignment(0, 0)
    grid.attach(self.locationLabel, 0, 2, 1, 1)
```

The solution was:

1. Add `POINTER_MOTION_MASK` to the event box: `box.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)`.
2. Connect `motion-notify-event` of the box with a method, which read and updated a label (down-left corner; it was aligned with `self.locationLabel.set_alignment(0, 0)`).