# Draw with mouse on a GTK DrawinArea using Cairo

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, drawingarea

I want to draw some points at the mouse position (on the click of the mouse)

I use Python with Cairo

I've written some code but it doesn't work very well (I see the points when I click on the buttons).

I made the GUI using Glade which is also linked at the end of question.

```
import os,sys,platform
    from os.path import join
    import cairo
    import gi

    class Interface:
        __gtype_name__ = "MonNom"

        def __init__(self):

            file_path = os.path.join('Interface.glade')
            interface = Gtk.Builder()
            interface.add_from_file(file_path)
            self.double_buffer = None
            interface.connect_signals(self)
            window = interface.get_object("window")            
            window.show_all()

        def on_draw(self, widget, cr):
            if self.double_buffer is not None:
                cr.set_source_surface(self.double_buffer, 0, 0)
                cr.paint()
            else:
                print('Invalid double buffer')
            return False

        def on_configure(self, widget, event, data=None):
            if self.double_buffer is not None:
                self.double_buffer.finish()
                self.double_buffer = None

            self.double_buffer = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 600,400)

            db = self.double_buffer
            cc = cairo.Context(db)
            cc.set_source_rgb(0,0, 0)
            cc.rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400)
            cc.set_source_rgb(1, 0, 0)
            cc.stroke()
            db.flush()
            return False

        def on_da_button_press(self, widget, event):
            print ("Mouse clicked... at ", event.x, ", ", event.y)
            # self.widget.queue_draw()
            db = self.double_buffer
            if db is not None:
                cc = cairo.Context(db)
                cc.move_to(event.x-5,event.y)
                cc.line_to(event.x+5,event.y)
                cc.move_to(event.x, event.y-5)
                cc.line_to(event.x, event.y+5)
                cc.set_source_rgb(0, 1, 0)
                cc.stroke()
                # db.flush()
            return True                 

        def on_destroy(self, widget):
            Gtk.main_quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = Interface()
        Gtk.main()
```

[The glade file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10uCnb9NjsdbB3TTz23G8GZ0SbBAEQ-IL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Imposible to add HELLO !

Comment: Relevant [gtk-how-to-detect-the-mouse-position-over-eventbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683788)

Comment: Hello, my problem is on the drawing not with the mouse and events

Comment: All the drawings are done when I clic on on button of the interface !

Comment: Resolved : It was a refresh proflem. I add self.window.queue_draw() in the end of 'on_da_button_press' and I'v changed the definition of 'window' in def __init__ (windows ->self.window)

Comment: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Comment: I had the same problem -- new points appeared if the window lost the mouse focus. The solution I came across was a bit different, though: the drawing area was refreshed, with, apparently, similar (or the same), result.
I wonder if there are significant differences, anyway.